# I face the error when trying to login to firebase using expo development build apkTypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Commands')

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

when I create a development build in expo and install it on real android device, it opens normally but when i try to login or signup to firebase database, it shows me the error:
pEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.power51214.AlRiaz&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:18816 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Commands')

This error is located at:
in AnimatedLoader (created by Loader)
in Loader (created by SignupScreen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View
in SafeAreaView (created by SignupScreen)
in SignupScreen (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View
in CardSheet (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Card)
in Card (created by CardContainer)
in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
in MaybeFreeze (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Background)
in Background (created by CardStack)
in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by App)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by App)
in ChildrenWrapper (created by Root)
in _default (created by Root)
in Root (created by RootSiblingParent)
in RootSiblingParent (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in ChildrenWrapper (created by Root)
in _default (created by Root)
in Root (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)
r

My code of login is here:

```
import { View, Text,TextInput, SafeAreaView,ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity,KeyboardAvoidingView,Platform, Alert } from 'react-native'
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import styles from './LoginScreenStyles';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import headerImage from '../../../assets/Images/largehead.png'
import {LinearGradient} from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import colors from '../../../assets/Colors/colors';
import Ionicon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import { StackActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Loader from '../../Components/Loader';
import { auth, db } from '../../../Firebase/firebase';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword,sendPasswordResetEmail } from 'firebase/auth';
import toast from '../../../assets/Functions/Toast';
import { onSnapshot, collection,query ,where} from 'firebase/firestore';



const LoginScreen = () => {
    const navigation=useNavigation()

    const [visible, setvisible] = useState(false)
    const [email, setemail] = useState('');
    const [password, setpassword] = useState('');
    const [loading, setloading] = useState(false)
// Login fubction
const login= async ()=>{
    if (email.length>0 && password.length>0) {
        setloading(true);
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password)
        .then( async userCred=>{
            // get Authorization status
          const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("id", "==", userCred.user.uid))
         await onSnapshot(q,(snapshot)=>{
            snapshot.forEach(user=>{
              if (user.data().authorization) {
                setloading(false)
                toast('User is LOGGED IN successfully!')
                navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('DrawerNavigator'))
              } else {
                setloading(false)
                Alert.alert('User is not Authorized to enter!')
              }
               
            })  
           
        },
        (error)=>{
            setloading(false);
            toast(error.message)
        })
        
        }).catch(error=>{
         setloading(false)
         Alert.alert('ERROR',error.message)
        })
    } else {
        Alert.alert('ALERT!','Please fill out all the fields')
    }
}
```

the other code is:

```
`
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
// import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";


// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);
// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export  {app,auth,db,storage};
`
```

I searched a lot but i didn,t find any solution related to this. Please help me if you get any solution